# In Flutter is there a way to have different navigation stacks

Tags: flutter, routes, navigation

I come from react-native and I am used to using react navigation, which allows you to make different stacks each with different routes in them.

Flutter appears to work where you have to put all your routes in one file, is there no way to split them up?

My app has 3 main sections and each screen in a section would ideally share blocs, but I cant find a way to make each section independent of the other sections which means either all the screens must share all the blocs or none of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you want every screen in section possible have a Navigator of itself ?

Default Flutter using a Navigator in app and navigate with *Navigator.of(...)*. An app can use more than one Navigator with Navigator Widget.

[Nesting Navigators](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Navigator-class.html)

[Code sample](https://github.com/bizz84/nested-navigation-demo-flutter)